# GitPython find most recent tag in the current branch only

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am using this code snippet with [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to capture the current branch, most recent commit, and most recent tag.  This information will be inserted into a version string.

```
repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
current_branch = str(repo.active_branch)
most_recent_tag = str(repo.tags[-1])
most_recent_commit = repo.head.object.hexsha[0:7]
num_commits_since_last_tag = len(list(repo.iter_commits(most_recent_tag + "..")))
```

As written, this code will find tags in other branches, not just the current branch. How can I  restrict my search for most recent tag to only tags that point to commits in the current branch?

Answer (score 0):

Found this snippet in the GitPython project issues.
https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/843

```
import git

r = git.Repo('path/to/foo')
output = r.git.tag(merged=True)
tags = output.split('\n')
```